# JavaScript color picker uses CSS syntax I'm not familiar with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jscolor which is a javascript color picker plugin ([link](http://jscolor.com/examples/)).

The documentation uses javascript inside the css class.

```html
<input class="jscolor {padding:20, borderWidth:3}">
```

How can I achieve this in javascript? I have not seen this before.

My other question is from the following piece of code that comes from jscolor's documentation. It is for showing and hiding the plugin.

```html
<script src="jscolor.js"></script>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('foo').jscolor.show()">
    Show Picker</button>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('foo').jscolor.hide()">
    Hide Picker</button>

<p><input id="foo" class="jscolor" value="cc4499">
```

How does this code call the plugin from just including the class `jscolor`?

and how does `document.getElementById('foo').jscolor.show()` call the plugin?

Particularly `jscolor.show()` does not make sense to me. Where does `jscolor` come from.

I tried replicating that code in jQuery and it did not work!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(button).click(function(){
  $('#foo').jscolor.show();
 });
});
```

Comment: Maybe they use some `eval` code to execute the JSON value like: `var instanceConfig = eval(foo.replace(/^jscolor\s+/, ""));`

Comment: It is not a class, it is just an object property. Try `$('#foo')[0].jscolor.show();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are doing some pretty atypical things with the class definition, so it's not surprising that the syntax would seem obscure.  But it isn't quite as it looks.  There are really just three CSS classes with weird names:

1. jscolor
2. {padding:20,
3. borderWidth:3}

In their js file, they use regular expressions to parse out the CSS values from these, and then apply them programmatically (logically, if an element has a jscolor class, then find a string beginning with `{` and ending with `}`, strip out the brackets and comma and use space as a delimiter, and you have your CSS attribute list to apply).  Presumably, they didn't want to ship a separate CSS file with the download.

As for your second question, they've just defined jscolor as a class, with its own methods and properties.  Their code, line 977:

```
jscolor : function (targetElement, options) {
```

With a whole lot of function calls defined inside this one.  Of which, on line 1046:

```
this.show = function () {
    drawPicker();
};
```

This code defines a function called `show()`; actually `jscolor.show()`.  So, `show()` calls the `drawPicker()` function, which actually handles the showing of the picker.  This means that their `show()` method is entirely unrelated to the `show()` method with which you're familiar.  They've defined their own.

If you study their code a bit on your own as you continue to use it, you'll begin to see more clearly what they're up to.  The jscolor class is a good example of how to write JS classes.  The class attribute stuff is definitely unusual, though.

Answer (score 1):

When jscolor is loaded with the src tag, it calls itself with a self executing function that on initiation looks for all `input` and `button` tags in the DOM that have the class `jscolor` and then adds a property called `jscolor` to them. That `jscolor` object is what you're calling when you do `onclick="document.getElementById('foo').jscolor.show()"`

The same logic that adds the jscolor object to the `input` and `button` tags also looks at the rest of the class data and parses things like `{padding:20, borderWidth:3}`. That's how that JavaScript-esque code is working in the CSS class.

All of this information was found from the jscolor github page: https://github.com/EastDesire/jscolor/blob/2.0.4/jscolor.js